# Getting 0 records while parsing json file , if the Key Attribute does not exists

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have few static key columns EmployeeId,type and few columns coming from first FOR loop.

While in the second FOR loop if i have a specific key then only values should be appended to the existing data frame columns else whatever the columns getting fetched from first for loop should remain same.

**First For Loop Output:**

```
"EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End","Country","Target","CountryId","TargetId"
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","","",""
```

**After Second For Loop i have below output:**

```
"EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End","Country","Target","CountryId","TargetId"
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","AMAZON","1",""
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","FLIPKART","2",""
```

As per code if i have Employee tag available , i have got above 2 records but i may have few json files without Employee tag then output should remain same as per First Loop Output with all the key fields populated and rest columns with null.

But i am getting 0 records as per my code. Please help me if my way of coding is wrong.

Please help me ... If the way of asking question is not clear i am sorry , as i am new to python .  Please find the sample data in the below link

**Please find below code**

```
    for i in range(len(json_file['enty'])):
        temp = {}
        temp['EmployeeId'] = json_file['enty'][i]['id']
        temp['type'] = json_file['enty'][i]['type']
        for key in json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes'].keys():        
            try:
                temp[key] = json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes'][key]['values'][0]['value']
            except:
                temp[key] = None      

        for key in json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes'].keys(): 
            if(key == 'Employee'):
                for j in range(len(json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'])):
                    for key in json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'][j].keys():
                        try:
                            temp[key] = json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'][j][key]['values'][0]['value']
                        except:
                            temp[key] = None

                    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([temp])
                    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], sort=True)

    # Rearranging columns
    df = df[['EmployeeId', 'type'] + [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['EmployeeId', 'type']]]

    # Writing the dataset
    df[columns_list].to_csv("Test22.csv", index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=1)
```

If Employee Tag is not available i am getting 0 records as output but i am expecting 1 record as for first for loop

[enter link description here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=672e1c8e543047a5a236d44c589f6476)

Comment: What is `json_file`? What is your expected output? Does your actual output have 2 records or 0 records?

Comment: @Goyo .. Thanks a lot Goyo for the reply.. I have attached sample json file above. Actually i have few key columns which will be available in every record in json file. Sometimes  Key Attribute will not be available then i am getting records but atleast key columns like Employee Id and type should be populated and rest columns can remain blank. But i am not able to get any records in the output csv file if "Employee" Tag is not available.

Comment: @Goyo .. Json files are my source file i am using to parse them by python and create a csv output file. Please help me how can i solve this issue..

Comment: @Goyo .. Please help me with any siggestion..

Comment: I am afraid I can't help much. I am still not sure what your expected output is, the code is too complex for me to understand and I can't run and debug it because there are too many undefined things. The best suggestion I can make is that you post a [mcve].

Comment: @Goyo. Actually i am getting 70% of expected output. that is if the source Json file has the Employee tag then i am getting as expected. But if i dont have the tag then atleast one record should be created with all the key columns required and rest of the columns can remain blank.

Comment: Of course you are free to ignore my suggestion.

Comment: @Ravi What is the expected output? Please share a sample of the csv based on the json data coming from https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=672e1c8e543047a5a236d44c589f6476

Comment: @balderman.. Thanks a lot for the reply..  Below is the expected output if i have employee tag.. 

"EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End","Country","Target","CountryId","TargetId"
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","2050-12-31","","AMAZON","1",""
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","2050-12-31","","FLIPKART","2",""

If i dont have employee tag then below is the expected output..

"EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End","Country","Target","CountryId","TargetId"
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","2050-12-31","","","",""

Answer (score 0):

The JSON structure is quite complicated. I try to simplified the data collection from it. The result is a list of flat dicts. The code handles the case where 'Employee' is not found.

```
import copy

d = {
    "enty": [
        {
            "id": "Emp1",
            "type": "Metal",
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "KeyColumn": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": 1212121212
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "End": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "2050-12-31"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Start": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "2000-06-17"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Employee": {
                        "group": [
                            {
                                "Target": {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "value": "AMAZON"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "CountryId": {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "value": "1"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "Target": {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "value": "FLIPKART"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "CountryId": {
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "value": "2"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
emps = []
for e in d['enty']:
    entry = {'id': e['id'], 'type': e['type']}
    for x in ["KeyColumn", "Start", "End"]:
        entry[x] = e['data']['attributes'][x]['values'][0]['value']
    if e['data']['attributes'].get('Employee'):
        for grp in e['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group']:
            clone = copy.deepcopy(entry)
            for x in ['Target', 'CountryId']:
                clone[x] = grp[x]['values'][0]['value']
            emps.append(clone)
    else:
        emps.add(entry)
# TODO write to csv
for emp in emps:
    print(emp)
```

output

```
{'End': '2050-12-31', 'Target': 'AMAZON', 'KeyColumn': 1212121212, 'Start': '2000-06-17', 'CountryId': '1', 'type': 'Metal', 'id': 'Emp1'}
{'End': '2050-12-31', 'Target': 'FLIPKART', 'KeyColumn': 1212121212, 'Start': '2000-06-17', 'CountryId': '2', 'type': 'Metal', 'id': 'Emp1'}
```